# How Use @can with @paginate together in Laravel lighthouse

Tags: graphql, pagination, directive, lighthouse, laravel-lighthouse

When I use @can in the query of getting all users like below I'm got an error that shows below:

```
getUsers(
      first_name: String @like(template : "%{}%") 
      last_name: String @like(template : "%{}%")
      email: String @like(template : "%{}%")      
      group_id: Int  
      # group_id: Group  @belongsToMany(relation: "groups" ) 
      orderBy: [OrderByClause!] @orderBy
       ): [User]  @guard(with:["api"]) @can(ability: "getAllUser") @paginate(builder: "App\\GraphQL\\Queries\\User\\GetUsers@resolveUser")
```

and get this error:

```
"debugMessage": "Failed to find class UserPaginator in namespaces [App, App\\Models] for directive @can.",
```

Comment: Are you on the latest version of lighthouse? I tried to reproduce this but couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in v5.45.3 of Lighthouse
https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse/releases/tag/v5.45.3

So you can fix your issue by simply updating Lighthouse.

Comment: I tried the latest version(5.57) but it didn't work.